# Why does every XML file I create with .net's XMLWriter fail W3C validation?

Tags: .net, vb.net, xmlwriter

The W3C validator tells me

```
Line 256, Column 12: non SGML character number 0
```

Both errors occur at the very end of the file.

Here is my abbreviated code:

```
            dim writer as XmlWriter
            dim xmlSettings as new XmlWriterSettings
            xmlSettings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
            xmlSettings.CheckCharacters = true
            xmlSettings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document
            xmlSettings.Indent = true

            writer = XmlWriter.Create("D:\somedata.xml", xmlSettings)

            writer.WriteStartDocument()
            writer.WriteStartElement("listings")

            while invReader.Read( )

                writer.WriteStartElement("listing")

                'a bunch of .writeElementString calls here

                writer.WriteEndElement()
            end while       
            writer.WriteEndElement()
            writer.WriteEndDocument()
            writer.Close()
```

Comment: Please show relevant parts of your xml.

Comment: The file generated using your code works just fine in my Firefox.

Comment: @svick you're right. I guess the data I am putting inside the listing elements is causing an anomaly to occur at the end of the file.

Comment: Ok, so I get no error in FireFox now, but the W3 validator tells me `Line 243, Column 12: character data is not allowed here </listings>` and it highlights a character after that last >. The problem is </listings> is the last tag in the file, and there is no character after it for me to examine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to write out a character that the validator thinks is illegal

Check out this link for an example of your error:

http://forums.htmlhelp.com/index.php?showtopic=11270

Comment: I agree that the validator is finding an invalid character, but it is at the end of the file after the last closing tag. When I open my XML file in a text editor, I can't even select the character that the validator says is an invalid character. The file ends at the character before.

Comment: maybe open the file in a hex editor and see what the character is. if its at the end, then its probably the code in WriteEndDocument  or WriteEndElement that is adding the invalid character. Maybe put a breakpoint and step through the code checking what is being written.